# In what cases would the logical reads increase but execution time would decrease?

Tags: sql-server, performance

When performance tuning a query, is it possible to decrease the execution time but increase the number of logical reads? This appeared to happen in one of my queries where I made a modification to a join and grouping onto a large table (the main change, I think, was doing the Group BY first and then doing join on that derived query) and it sped up the execution but increased the number of logical reads.  Why is that and what type of changes might lead to that?

SQL Server

Comment: What else changed? Logical reads (that aren't physical reads) come from memory so probably have less impact on duration, on their own, than you think. Maybe you could post the actual execution plans (the .sqlplan files, not just screen shots) somewhere, and folks could take a look?

Comment: Yes, the buffer cache could be a factor. Between runs try this: checkpoint, dbcc dropcleanbuffers, dbcc freeproccache. That should help to level the playing field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical reads measure is not a good one because it does not account for reads from buffer pool (cache). I consider this metric to be mostly useless with a few exceptions.

> In what cases would the logical reads increase but execution time would decrease?

A nested loop join with an index seek produces at least one logical read. If all pages read are cached though the actual cost of this operation will be very low.

So you see logical reads is a very misleading counter. Try to optimize for actual, physical IO, for CPU usage and for latency.

Comment: Thanks @usr, that makes sense. I also came across [this article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2010/logical-reads/) that explains more in detail.